# Compare millions of records from Oracle to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, ssis

I have an Oracle database and a SQL Server database. There is one table say `Inventory` which contains millions of rows in both database tables and it keeps growing.

I want to compare the Oracle table data with the SQL Server data to find out which records are missing in the SQL Server table on daily basis.

Which is best approach for this?

1. Create SSIS package.
2. Create Windows service.

I want to consume less resource to achieve this functionality which takes less time and less resource.

Eg : 18 millions records in oracle and 16/17 millions in SQL Server

This situation of two different database arise because two different application online and offline

**EDIT** : How about connecting SQL server from oracle through Oracle Gateway to SQL server to

1) Direct query to SQL server from Oracle to update missing record in SQL server for 1st time.

2) Create a trigger on Oracle which gets executed when record is deleted from Oracle and it insert deleted record in new oracle table.

3) Create SSIS package to map newly created oracle table with SQL server to update SQL server record.This way only few records have to process daily through SSIS.

What do you think of this approach ?

Comment: I think a good long term strategy would be to not store your state across different RDBMS.  Could you update the question explaining how you ended up with this problem?

Comment: Can you explain us how records are duplicated at the moment?

Comment: Oracle database has all the records.. and there is possibility that records gets deleted from oracle database and we have to update SQL server records which got deleted from oracle database

Comment: So not only do you want to compare, you want to insert (and update?) changes. You might want to add that to your question.

Comment: Yes your edits are talking about differential replication which I mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an SSIS package and load the data from the Oracle table use a Data Flow / OLE DB Data Source.  If you have SQL Enterprise, the Attunity Connectors are a bit faster.

Then I would load key from the SQL Server table into a Lookup transformation, where I would match the 2 sources on the key, and direct unmatched rows into a separate output.

Finally I would direct the unmatched rows output to a OLE DB Command, to update the SQL Server table.

This SSIS package will require a lot of memory, but as the matching is done in memory with minimal IO, it will probably outperform other solutions for speed. It will need enough free memory to cache all the keys from the SQL Server Table.

SSIS also has the advantage that it has lots of other transformation functions available if you need them later.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So you are suggesting that SSIS package is best approach to compare 18 Millions of oracle record with 15/16 millions of SQL server record with SSIS lookup ??

Comment: Yes, due to minimal IO. SSIS only needs to read from the Oracle and SQL Server tables once and it will then match in memory, where most other techniques require reading and writing (and then reading again) one of your large datasets.

Comment: I don't think the SSIS Lookup is going to be able to handle that volume (I'm happy to be corrected though). If there is any degree of complexity (i.e. case insensitive or range lookups), it has to do the lookup row by row which will be very slow for 18 million records.

Comment: I'm imagining a typical key match e.g. all columns are numeric or can be matched as case-sensitive, so I would use the default Full Cache mode for the Lookup.  As I mentioned this will need enough memory e.g. 18m x average key length. E.g. if the key was a single int / DT_I4 column, then that's 18m x 4 bytes = 72MB.

Answer (score 1):

What you basically want to do is replication from Oracle to SQL Server.

You could do this in SSIS, A windows Service or indeed a multitude of platforms. 
The real trick is using the correct design pattern.

There are two general design patterns

1. Snapshot Replication

You take **all** records from both systems and compare them somewhere (so far we have suggestions to compare in SSIS or compare on Oracle but not yet a suggestion to compare on SQL Server, although this is valid)

You are comparing 18 million records here so this is a lot of work

2. Differential replication

You record the changes in the publisher (i.e. Oracle) since the last replication then you apply those changes to the subscriber (i.e. SQL Server)

You can do this manually by implementing triggers and log tables on the Oracle side, then use a regular ETL process (SSIS, command line tools, text files, whatever), probably scheduled in SQL Agent to apply these to the SQL Server.

Or you could do this by using the out of the box replication capability to set up Oracle as a publisher and SQL as a subscriber: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151149(v=sql.105).aspx

You're going to have to try a few of these and see what works for you.

Given this objective:

> > I want to consume less resource to achieve this functionality which takes less time and less resource

transactional replication is far more efficient but complicated. For maintenance purposes, which platforms (.Net, SSIS, Python etc.) are you most comfortable with?

Answer (score 0):

Other alternatives:

If you can use Oracle gateway for SQL Server then you do not need to transfer data and can make the query directly.

If you can't use Oracle gateway, you can use Pentaho data integration or another ETL tool to compare tables and get results. Is easy to use.

Comment: Your answer is pretty vague, at least for me, as it does not give any clue as how to achieve this. Also consider the case that one application is offline.

Comment: Hi. I only suggested an alternative to the transfer of data with procedures. With oracle gateway for SQLServer you can do the comparation directly. The same with ETL tool but this alternative is diferent.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is using oracle gateway.Just follow the steps. I have similar type of experience.

1. Install and Configure Oracle Database Gateway for SQL Server.
   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/gateways.111/b31042/installsql.htm
2. Now you can create a dblink from oracle to sql server.
3. Create a procedure which compare the missing records in oracle database and insert into sql server database.

For example, you can use this statement inside your procedure.

```
    INSERT INTO "dbo"."sql_server_table"@dblink_name("column1","column2"...."column5")
VALUES
(
    select column1,column2....column5 from oracle_table
    minus
   select "column1","column2"...."column5" from "dbo"."sql_server_table"@dblink_name
)
```

4. Create a scheduler which execute the procedure daily.

When both databases are online, missing records will be inserted to sql server. Otherwise the scheduler fail or you can execute the procedure manually.
It takes minimum resource.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest having a homemade ETL solution.

1. Schedule an [oracle job](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm) to export source table data (on a daily
   manner based on the application logic ) [to plain CSV](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:88212348059) format.
2. Schedule a [SQL-Server job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx) (with acceptable delay from first oracle job) to read this CSV file and import it
   to a medium table inside sql-servter using [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).
3. Last part of the SQL-Server job will be reading medium table data
   and do the logic(insert, update target table). I suggest having another table to store reports of this daily job result.